# How to check that the string is not nil in swift?

Tags: string, swift

If I declared a `String` like this: `var date  = String()`

and I want to check if it is a `nil` `String` or not,
so that I try something like:

```
if date != nil{
    println("It's not nil")
}
```

But I got an error like : `Can not invoke '!=' with an argument list of type '(@lvalue String, NilLiteralConvertible)'`

after that I try this:

```
if let date1 = date {
    println("It's not nil")
}
```

But still getting an error like:

`Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type`

So my question is how can I check that the `String` is not `nil` **if I declare it this way**?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The string *can't* be nil. That's the point of this sort of typing in Swift.

If you want it to be possibly nil, declare it as an optional:

```
var date : String?
```

If you want to check a string is *empty* (don't do this, it's the sort of thing optionals were made to work around) then:

```
if date.isEmpty
```

But you really should be using optionals.

Comment: It does not answer the question how to check optional variable for nil.

Comment: @TomasLiubinas: AFAIK, the compiler won't let you write code that nil-checks a `String`, you can only do this on a `String?`

Answer (score 6):

You may try this...

```
var date : String!
...
if let dateExists = date {
      // Use the existing value from dateExists inside here.
}
```

Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 2):

In your example the string cannot be nil. To declare a string which can accept nil you have to declare optional string:

```
var date: String? = String()
```

After that declaration your tests will be fine and you could assign nil to that variable.

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit late but might help others. You can create an optional string extension. I did the following to set an optional string to empty if it was nil :

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == String {

    mutating func setToEmptyIfNil() {
        guard self != nil else {
            self = ""
            return
        }
    }

}
```