# Why does String implicitly become String! in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I received a compilation error from Xcode yesterday, saying

> Binary operator '&&' cannot be applied to two Bool operands <sup>[1]</sup>

on

```
if text != nil && presentingViewController != nil {
    ...
}
```

`text` is defined earlier as

```
var text: String = "" {
    didSet {
        ...
    }
}
```

and `presentingViewController` is from `UIViewController`, which is the `super` class.

A friend of mine told me that it was caused by `text`, which was of `String!`, and the issue was solved by changing

```
var text: String
```

to

```
var text: String?
```

However, it still puzzles me why my explicitly defined `String` becomes `String!`. Can anyone provide any detail on this implicit conversion?

<sub>[1] This compilation error does not make sense, and this question is not a duplicate of [another question of the same compilation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30822070/binary-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-two-bool-operands).</sub>

Comment: Isn't String? a 'wrapped' String? And you use '!' to unwrap the '?' ?. This would mean that String defined without '?' would automatically be 'unwrapped'

Comment: a good explaination could be:

[Check that string is not nil in swift][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27482537/how-to-check-that-the-string-is-not-nil-in-swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is related to what is called "optionals" in swift.

In Objective-C you could have a reference to NSString and it could either be pointing to an NSString instance - or to nil. In swift this is different!

A "regular" String in swift can never be nil. Only an "optional" String can be nil. This is how it would look in swift code:

```
var myRegularString  : String      // this can never be nil, can't compare to nil
var myOptionalString : String?     // this can be nil (note the ?)
```

You have a "regular" String. So the compiler complains when you try to compare it to nil.

Optionals are explained here: [Swift Programming Language/Basics/Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330)

Answer (score 2):

Your explicitly defined `String` is not `String!` is ... `String`. Simple like that ;-)

`String!` is an *implicitly unwrapped* `Optional<String>`

`String?` is an `Optional<String>`

`Optional<T>` means that it can be a value of type `T` or `Nothing` (and nothing can be compared to `nil`).

Thus when you declare:

```
var text = ""
```

you declare an actual String and it cannot be `nil`. That's why the compiler is complaining: *a String cannot be `Nothing`*. Think of it as comparing a `String` with a `CGFloat` ... the compiler will complain.

Since `String!` is an `Optional<String>` than it can be compared against `nil`.
The `!` simply is you declaring that you are absolutely sure it is not `Nothing` such that you can use `text` without *unwrapping* its actual value.

BTW, do not confuse and *empty String* (i.e.: `""`) with `Nothing`. 
`var text = ""` is an actual `String` just empty and it is not comparable with `Nothing`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Maybe in the code from your example, you'd prefer using `var text = ""` and in your `if` statement check if `text.isEmpty`

Answer (score 1):

Your friend most certainly didn't solve your problem, he just glossed over it.

You declared an instance variable of type String. text will always be a String. It can never, ever be nil. Asking "text != nil" is pointless because it cannot be nil. It doesn't even compile, because a String, always being nil, cannot even checked for being nil.

Your friend suggested to use String? or String!. That's in your situation total nonsense. You have text which is guaranteed to be always a String. Instead you change it to text which may be a String or nil. This doesn't help you in any way. Yes, now you can ask it whether it is nil. Before, you didn't even have to ask.